# Pandas / Numpy: How to Turn Column Data Into Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm working on an iPython project with Pandas and Numpy.  I'm just learning too so this question is probably pretty basic.  Lets say I have two columns of data

```
---------------
| col1 | col2 | 
---------------
| a    | b    |
| c    | d    |
| b    | e    |
---------------
```

I want to transform this data of the form.

```
---------------------
| a | b | c | d | e |
---------------------
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
---------------------
```

Then I want to take a three column version

```
---------------------
| col1 | col2 | val | 
---------------------
| a    | b    | .5  |
| c    | d    | .3  |
| b    | e    | .2  |
---------------------
```

and turn it into

```
---------------------------
| a | b | c | d | e | val |
---------------------------
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | .5  |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | .3  |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | .2  |
---------------------------
```

I'm very new to Pandas and Numpy, how would I do this?  What functions would I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`pandas.get_dummies()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) function and [`pandas.DataFrame.combineAdd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combineAdd.html) method.

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('acb'),
                           'col2': list('bde'),
                           'val': [.5, .3, .2]})

In [8]: df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.col1)

In [9]: df2 = pd.get_dummies(df.col2)
```

This produces the following two dataframes:

```
In [16]: df1
Out[16]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0

[3 rows x 3 columns]

In [17]: df2
Out[17]: 
   b  d  e
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Which can be combined as follows:

```
In [10]: dummies = df1.combineAdd(df2)

In [18]: dummies
Out[18]: 
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  1  0
2  0  1  0  0  1

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

The last step is to copy the `val` column into the new dataframe.

```
In [19]: dummies['val'] = df.val

In [20]: dummies
Out[20]: 
   a  b  c  d  e  val
0  1  1  0  0  0  0.5
1  0  0  1  1  0  0.3
2  0  1  0  0  1  0.2

[3 rows x 6 columns]
```